# Page through a relativelayout android

Tags: android, pagination, android-relativelayout

I programmatically create buttons and add them into a relativelayout, whose parent is a HorizontalScrollView,

Occasionally the layout becomes really long and it would be nice to have a pager button that would jump from item #1 to the items 1 page over...

Is there any method(s) that would help me in placing an item i into slot #1 in the visible portion of the layout?

I can adjust my model to a LinearLayout if it's an option.

Thanks!

Comment: i am sure you want to put Previout-next buttons to view items, is it right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my understanding you are trying to flip between a group a buttons.
One way to flip between group of buttons would be to use a viewflipper. Keep a group of buttons in a linear layout. So when you want to flip to the next group use the

```
viewflipper.setDisplayChild(1);
```

Another way would be to use the viewpager. Using the view pager will allow you to flip between layout by just sliding.

This might be of use, it is a [blog post](http://paulononaka.wordpress.com/2011/03/19/how-to-implement-a-paging-feature-in-android/) about pagination. And [here is the source code](https://github.com/paulononaka/Android-PaginationLayoutSample).